# angular how to lazy load layout-component without destroying on route change

Tags: angular

I'm lazy loading routes but since the layout component is quite heavy I also want this lazily loaded. How do I achieve this without reloading the layout component on a route change?

For example:

app-routing.module.ts routes:

```
  { path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(l => l.HomeModule) }, 
  { path: 'page1', loadChildren: () => import('./profile/page1.module').then(x => x.ProfileModule1) },
  { path: 'page2', loadChildren: () => import('./profile/page2.module').then(x => x.ProfileModule2) },
  { path: 'page3', loadChildren: () => import('./profile/page3.module').then(x => x.ProfileModule3) }
```

page1, page2 and page3 all have `MainNavComponent` as layout. I also want to have it lazily loaded. So in all page modules are routed like this:

page1.module.ts:

```
RouterModule.forChild([
            {
                path: '',
                children: [
                   { path: '', component: Page1Component }
                ],
                component: MainNavComponent
            }]
        ),
```

Page 2 and Page 3 have the same setup.
The problem is when routing from page1 to page2 or page3, MainNavComponent gets destroyed because of the route change.

How can I set this up in a way that MainNavComponent isn't included in the main bundle?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of making the `MainNavComponent` a global/root level component?

Let's say in your app.component.html

```
<main-nav-component></main-nav-component>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

In this way, your page1, page2, page3 and other routes will be projected into the router-outlet with the main-nav-component intact(Won't be destroyed on route changed).

Or

You can also divide your routes into "has main nav" and "doesn't have main nav"

```
{
    path: 'withOutMainNav',
    loadChildren: () => import('childRoutingModule')....( child routing module which doesn't contains the main nav )
},
{
    path: 'withMainNav',
    loadChildren: () => import('hasMainNavModule')
}
```

In the routing file of hasMainNavModule

```
{
    path: '',
    component: AComponentWithMainNavAndRouterOutlet,
    loadChildren: () => import('childRoutingModule')....( child routing module which contains your child routes that will be projected alongside the main nav )
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks but that won't lazy load the main-nav. There are other layouts too which would then also have to load the main-nav, which is expensive.

Comment: Yes, it will get expensive if your application contains routes that won't contain the Main Nav. 

I have added another approach in my answer that could help.